# For how many $n$ is $2021^n$ + $2022^n$ + $2023^n$ + ... + $2029^n$ prime?

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

For how many $n$ is $2021^n$ + $2022^n$ + $2023^n$ + ... + $2029^n$ prime?

My first thought is set x = 2021 so we can create:

$x^n$ + $(x+1)^n$ + $(x+2)^n$ + ... + $(x+8)^n$

And then we expand each term even though we don't know $n$?

So for example: $(x+1)^n$ = $x^n$ + $\dbinom{n}{1}$$x^{n-1}$ + $\dbinom{n}{2}$ $x^{n-2}$ + ... +  $\dbinom{n}{n-1}$ $x^{n-(n-1)}$ + $\dbinom{n}{n}$ $x^{n-n}$

I understand this, but how do I go about showing that the original sum is prime?

I don't think some obvious pattern will arise when I've expanded every term that will show whether or not it is prime.

Comment: I don;t know how to prove it, but [Wolfram Alpah](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2021%5En%2B2022%5En%2B2023%5En%2B2024%5En%2B2025%5En%2B2026%5En%2B2027%5En%2B2028%5En%2B2029%5En+is+prime+for+which+n%3F) seems to say that the value of that expression is divisible by $5$ when $n\neq 4k$ and divisible by $3$ when $n=4k$

Comment: A good idea when working with consecutive numbers is to take the middle term here $x=2025$ then you have $(x-4)^n+(x-3)^n+\cdots+(x+3)^n +(x+4)^n$, now in this case it's not that useful though it makes it sort of obvious that for odd $n$ the expression is divisible by $x$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Note that $x^n$, $(x+3)^n$ and $(x+6)^n$ give the same remaider when divided by $3$. So, the sum $x^n+(x+3)^n+(x+6)^n$ must be divisible by $3$.

Now, the expression in the question can be written as
$$(2021^n+2024^n+2027^n)+(2022^n+2025^n+2028^n)+(2023^n+2026^n+2029^n)$$
which proves that this sum is divisible by $3$.

So, none of those expressions are prime.